# Deleting Duplicate Rows in VIew in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables, `TABLE1` and `TABLE2`. `TABLE1` Has 4 columns: `Name`, `Client`, `Position`, and `ID`. `TABLE2` has 3 columns: `Amount`, `Time`, and `ID`. For every `ID` in `TABLE1` there are one or more entries in `TABLE2`, all with identical `ID` and `Time` values but varying `Amount` values.

In a view, I have a concatenated string of `Name`, `Client`, `Position`, and `ID` from `TABLE1`, but I also need to concatenate the `Time` for each `ID` from `TABLE2` to this string. If I do a join as I create the view, I get a ton of duplicate strings in the view as it lists the same `ID` multiple times for each value of `Amount` in `TABLE2`.

I need to get rid of the duplicates, so I either need to avoid the replication that occurs from the join, or find a way to simply delete all the duplicates from the view.

Hopefully this is all clear enough. Thank you for reading and for any help you can provide!

Comment: Try using `DISTINCT` while SELECTing the data for the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DISTINCT` could be appropriate:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[View1]
AS
SELECT distinct 
  dbo.Table1.Id, 
  dbo.Table1.Name, 
  dbo.Table1.Client,
  dbo.Table1.Position, 
  dbo.Table2.[Time]
FROM dbo.Table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Table2 
ON dbo.Table1.Id = dbo.Table2.Id
```

SqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65651/1

On a side note, depending on what your table structures really are, you might consider having a surrogate primary key on the table2 if you don't have a natural one. I have not put one in the example, because chances are that you already have one - just making sure.

Comment: Yup that did it. Feel a little foolish I didn't try that haha. Thanks!